# Internet Explorer - Flash automation with WatiN library?

Tags: c#, flash, automation, watin

Does anyone know of a way to script flash objects using WatiN?

I need a way to send arbitrary keystrokes to a flash application. I'm able to login with code such as this:

```
ie.TextField(Find.ById("email")).TypeText(username);
ie.TextField(Find.ById("password")).TypeText(password);
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
ie.FlashObject(Find.ById("flash-object")).TypeText("123");
```

Or if focus is set to the browser, flash responds, so free text would work:

```
ie.FreeText.TypeText("123");
```

Currently I'm using a windows forms app with SendKeys() and it's not very robust.

Thanks.

Comment: Flash can be automated? If so,this should be interesting.

Comment: I wound up using the AutoItX library (http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) because WatiN doesnt seem to be able to access flash components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Ruby library called [FlashWatir](http://code.google.com/p/flash-watir/). Not exactly what you were looking for, but close.